# How to subscribe again with Mandrill API?

Tags: footer, mailchimp, mandrill, unsubscribe

Can user subscribe again after unsubscribe from Mandrill API.
And also can we use the default footer unsubscribe link for specific template.
If i check the "Add Unsubscribe Footer" in Mandrill API then unsubscribe shows on all emails but i want to show on specific emails.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, people can subscribe again after clicking the Mandrill unsub link, but you'd need to handle that manually since Mandrill doesn't store any lists for you. For example, if someone unsubscribes and then contacts you to say it was an accident and they want to receive your emails again, you would need to remove them from the Mandrill [rejection blacklist](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582977) and update their status on your own list outside of Mandrill if you're keeping everything in sync.

The "Add Unsubscribe Footer" option on the Sending Defaults page is all-or-nothing, so you can't selectively include it on some templates. Instead, you'll need to disable that option entirely and add the Mandrill [unsub merge tag](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583017) only in the templates you want.

Comment: Not to mention when you remove an item from the blacklist your reputation takes a hit! That's no fun :(

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to handle this.

---

Have a 'Subscribe again' link in your email template, which will redirect to your application page, which(onload) can use MANDRILL API to delete the user from rejection list.

Please visit the link below to know about deleting the user from rejection list.

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/rejects.python.html#method=delete

---

(OR)

---

hide the 'Unsubscribe link' in the mail.

Settings -> Sending defaults -> Uncheck - Add Unsubscribe Footer.

And then have the control/settings in your App to subscribe/unsubscribe.

This setting will be in your database whether to pick this user or not.

---

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/rejects.ruby.html#method=delete API method for renew subscription.
2. You can manually put {{UNSUB}} tag, with own link for particular process unsubscription. https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582947-About-Unsubscribes